# Confidence intervals for binary classification

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, accuracy

I'm doing binary classification in Python with an SVM classifier, and I implemented stratified repeated cross validation to have more robust results.

I would like to calculate confidence intervals for the mean accuracy, but using normal distribution assumption (if my code is correct) I obtain unrealistically narrow CIs.
I know that another approach is to use bootstrapping, but I have some confusion and I am unsure if I can use bootstrapping together with cross-validation.

Below is a toy example with the dataset breast_cancer where the accuracy is relatively stable from one run to another. However I have data with smaller sample size, where the accuracy can range a lot.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import scipy.stats as stats
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True)
X = df['data']
y = df['target']

n_runs = 5

accuracies = []

for i in range(n_runs):
    # Split the data into training and testing sets using KFold
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
    for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=None)
        svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
        accuracies.append(accuracy)

mean_accuracy = np.mean(accuracies)
std_accuracy = np.std(accuracies)
n_samples = len(accuracies)
z_score = stats.norm.ppf(0.975)  
margin_of_error = z_score * sqrt((mean_accuracy*(1-mean_accuracy))/n_samples)

accuracy_CI = (mean_accuracy - margin_of_error, mean_accuracy + margin_of_error)
```

**EDIT:**

I found a way to compute the confidence interval, calculating the difference between the mean_accuracy and each value of accuracy obtained from each run of the classifier. That should be a bootstrap approach.
Is that correct?

````
result_tot=[]
for i in accuracies:
    result=i-mean_accuracy
    result_tot.append(result)
    
pct_05 = np.percentile(result_tot, 2.5)
pct_95 = np.percentile(result_tot, 97.5)

print("0.05 percentile:", mean_accuracy+pct_05)
print("0.95 percentile:", mean_accuracy+pct_95)
```
````

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) with a few of many available options. Your `std_accuracy = np.std(accuracies)` looks unconventional (it is more usual to use the estimated proportion or something related to it) and I suspect your division by `np.sqrt(n_samples)` may not be appropriate if you take this route.

Comment: Thanks @Henry , I corrected with `margin_of_error = z_score * sqrt((mean_accuracy*(1-mean_accuracy))/n_samples)`